# Converting cv::Mat to unsigned int pixels

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to convert cv::Mat to unsigned int buffer image, The conversion is not working, I get a black image

```
    Mat srcIm, edges;
    srcIm = imread("15016889798859437.jpg");
    cv::cvtColor(srcIm, srcIm, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    unsigned int *finalSrc = new unsigned int[srcIm.rows*srcIm.cols*3];

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(srcIm.data);

        for (int i = 0; i < srcIm.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < srcIm.cols; j++) {
                 int r, g, b;
                r = input[srcIm.step * j + i];
                g = input[srcIm.step * j + i + 1];
                b = input[srcIm.step * j + i + 2];

                int rgb = ((r & 0x0ff) << 16) | ((g & 0x0ff) << 8) | (b & 0x0ff);

                finalSrc[i+ j*srcIm.rows] = rgb;
            }
        }

        cv::Mat videoFrame(srcIm.rows, srcIm.cols, CV_32SC1, finalSrc);
```

UPDATED CODE:

Following the comments, I have solved the mistakes, but still I get white image.

```
unsigned int *finalSrc = new unsigned int[srcIm.rows*srcIm.cols];

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(srcIm.data);

    int cn = srcIm.channels();

    for (int i = 0; i < srcIm.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < srcIm.cols; j++)
        {
            int r, g, b;

            r = input[(i * srcIm.cols * srcIm.channels()) + (j*srcIm.channels()) + 0];
            g = input[(i * srcIm.cols * srcIm.channels()) + (j*srcIm.channels()) + 1];
            b = input[(i * srcIm.cols * srcIm.channels()) + (j*srcIm.channels()) + 2];

            int rgb = ((r & 0x0ff) << 16) | ((g & 0x0ff) << 8) | (b & 0x0ff);

        }
    }

    cv::Mat videoFrame(srcIm.rows, srcIm.cols, CV_32S, finalSrc);


    imshow("v", videoFrame);
```

Comment: To access an specific pixel in an array, inside too loops whose variables are `i` and `j`, you should `image[(i * image.cols * image.channels)+(j*image.channels)+desiredChannel]`

Comment: You mean in finalSrc assignment ?

Comment: The `cvtColor` is rather useless -- you could just swap `r` with `b` in the loop. `finalSrc` seems to be 3x the necessary size. The input indexing is also quite unnecessary, you could just iterate over the elements.

Comment: @DanMašek Can you post an answer please with these adjustments ?

Comment: No, `r`, `g`, `b` assignment

Comment: opencv doesn't support unsigned int type, only signed int (.convertTo(CV_32S))

Comment: @Micka I converted cv::Mat videoFrame(srcIm.rows, srcIm.cols, CV_32S, finalSrc);
but still I get white image

Comment: I have updated the code regarding the comments, but I still get white image

Comment: as I said, openCV doesn't allow UNSIGNED int, only signed int. In your question it is completelty unclear what you want to achieve, if you want a single int to represent RGB values, use CV_8UC4 instead, encoding 1 int to be BGRA values. Currently you are creating a single channel Mat which uses uninitialized memory values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO there are multiple opportunities to simplify the code.

1. Drop the `cvtColor`. You're iterating over the elements anyway, so just swap `r` and `b` in your loop body and you can avoid the conversion.
2. `finalSrc` array is 3x the needed size. It's a single channel `Mat`, so you just need `srcIm.rows * srcIm.cols` elements.
3. No need for such complex indexing. The `Mat`s are the same shape, so you can just iterate over the elements.
4. Don't even iterate, use an algorithm instead -- `std::transform` is a good fit for this.
5. Don't expect to be able to visualize the result using `cv::imshow`. From the docs:

   > If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].

   Your values use 24 bits, so vast majority of them will exceed `255*256`, and will saturate to white.

Note: I'm using "typed" `Mat`s (e.g. `cv::Mat3b`, `cv::Mat1i`). Those "know" the contained data type, which makes using them somewhat simpler.

Note: I'm filling the input image with a sequence of values. The first pixel will have `(B=0, G=1, R=2)`, second `(B=3, G=4, R=5)`, and so on. This makes it simple to verify the results.

---

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    // Generate a sample image.
    cv::Mat3b srcIm(4, 4);
    std::iota(srcIm.data, srcIm.data + srcIm.rows * srcIm.cols * 3, 0);

    cv::Mat1i videoFrame(srcIm.rows, srcIm.cols);

    // Perform the conversion
    std::transform(srcIm.begin(), srcIm.end(), videoFrame.begin()
        , [](cv::Vec3b const& v) {
            return v[0] | (v[1] << 8) | (v[2] << 16);
        });

    // Display results
    for (auto const& v : videoFrame) {
        std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << v << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
020100
050403
080706
0b0a09
0e0d0c
11100f
141312
171615
1a1918
1d1c1b
201f1e
232221
262524
292827
2c2b2a
2f2e2d
```

---

You mention you want the result as an array. Same principle will apply.

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned int[]> result(new unsigned int[srcIm.rows * srcIm.cols]);

std::transform(srcIm.begin(), srcIm.end(), result.get()
    , [](cv::Vec3b const& v) {
        return v[0] | (v[1] << 8) | (v[2] << 16);
    });
```

Comment: The thing is I want to store the cv::Mat into unsigned int []

Comment: @andre Same principle will apply, just replace `videoFrame`.

Comment: @andre In what sense does it not work? Can you elaborate, please? Unfortunately I don't have a copy of VS2017 to test it with, but it definitely seems a bit odd, it's been part of the c++ for ages now. Perhaps I missed an include, it should be in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: It's a security issue, so I disabled the warning. But thanks for the answer. Is it possible to see the result in a cv::Mat, I know its not possible, but I converted the videoFrame to CV_32S

Comment: an off question, how do I calculate the stride for a cv::Mat

Comment: @andre Please, post that as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849832/how-do-i-calculate-the-stride-for-a-cvmat