# how do I calculate the stride for a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to know how would I calculate the stride of a `cv:Mat`.

I have updated the code, where I need to calculate the stride, I don't know what's wrong to calculate the projective transformation.
I get a `cv::Mat` then copy it to `unsigned int` array, then do the transformation on it, then get back a `cv::Mat` to be shown.

```cpp
cv::Mat3b  srcIm;
srcIm = imread("15016889798859437.jpg");
cv::Mat3b  srcIm, edges;
srcIm = imread("Lenna.png");
   
image_t src, dst;
int n_bytes_for_each_row = srcIm.step;

src.width = srcIm.rows;
src.height = srcIm.cols;
 
src.stride = n_bytes_for_each_row;
 
dst.width = 350;
dst.height = 350;
dst.stride = n_bytes_for_each_row;
dst.pixels = new unsigned int[350*350];
   
std::unique_ptr<unsigned int[]> videoFrame(new unsigned int[srcIm.rows * srcIm.cols]);

std::transform(srcIm.begin(), srcIm.end(), videoFrame.get()
    , [](cv::Vec3b const& v) {
    return v[0] | (v[1] << 8) | (v[2] << 16);
});

vertex_t vert[4];
vert[0].u = 0;
vert[0].v = 0;
vert[0].x = 0;
vert[0].y = 0;

vert[1].u = 50;
vert[1].v = 0;
vert[1].x = 350;
vert[1].y = 0;
//
vert[2].u = 150;
vert[2].v = 350;
vert[2].x = 350;
vert[2].y = 350;
//
vert[3].u = 0;
vert[3].v = 50;
vert[3].x = 0;
vert[3].y = 350;

src.pixels = videoFrame.get();
perspective_transform(&src, &dst, vert);

cv::Mat videoFrameMat(350, 350, CV_32S, dst.pixels);

double min;
double max;
cv::minMaxIdx(videoFrameMat, &min, &max);
cv::Mat adjMap;
cv::convertScaleAbs(videoFrameMat, adjMap, 255 / max);
cv::imshow("Out", adjMap);

cv::waitKey();
```

Comment: By stride, do you mean the number of bytes between the start of two rows? (presumably caused by row padding)

Comment: @Frank yes I would like to calculate image stride, the number of bytes

Comment: sorry so late, but the stride must be used when allocating memory not the row count otherwise it may not "line up" correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [step](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

> **step** – Number of bytes each matrix row occupies

```
int n_bytes_for_each_row = mat.step;
```

Comment: Please take a look at the modified question

Comment: @andre and what `dst_image` and `src_image` are supposed to be? The edited question is completely different from the original

Comment: dst_image is unsigned int [dst_image->width*dst_image->height] and src_image is a modified cvMat that is copied into unsigned int

Comment: Miki, I'm trying to do perspective transformation https://github.com/marcantonio/imagekiln/blob/master/perspective.c

Comment: Mike, please take a look at the original question

Comment: I'm sorry but this has nothing to do with the original question, which is the one I answered to. Good luck